# Passing data to React Modal inside loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, reactive-programming

I have a React/Webpack App that I am having some problems with. I'm pretty new to React, so I think I am missing something rather simple.

I have an array for saved addresses for a user account. I am attempting to add an edit button that launches a modal so the user can edit a specific saved address.

Here is my code to go loop through the saved addresses and displays the button:

```
<React.Fragment>
    {savedAddresses.map(data => {
    const address = {
      firstName: data.firstname,
      lastName: data.lastname,
      address1: data.address1,
      address2: data.address2,
      address3: data.address3,
      city: data.city,
      state: data.state,
      postalCode: data.postalcode,
      country: data.country
    };
    const contact = {
      email: data.email,
      phoneNumber: data.phonenumber
    };
    return (
      <div className="saved-address" styleName="styles.saved-address" key= 
    {data.name}>
        <AppliedAddress address={address} contact={contact} />
        <button styleName="form.submit"
          onClick={() => this.submitSavedAddress(data.name)}>
          Send to this Address
        </button>
        <button styleName="form.submit"
          onClick={() => this.openEditAddressModal()}>
          Edit
        </button>
        {this.state.isEditingAddress && (
          <EditAddressModal
            firstName={data.firstName}
          />
        )}
        {this.state.isProcessing && <ProcessingAnimation />}
      </div>
    )
  })}
</React.Fragment>
```

The modal is launching, but the data I am passing in is being updated for every saved address, and when loading the modal the data shows the last saved address not the address which was clicked. In this example I am passing the first name field.

I have three saved addresses with unique first name's [Dan, Eric, Jane].

I added a debugger and I can see the first name field being updated for each address, so that when the modal is loaded, "Jane" is always selected even when clicking the button on "Dan's" address.

Does anyone know what I might be missing in order to only pass the data on the selected address?

I assumed isEditingAddress being false on the other addresses would prevent that data from being passed, but it seems that is not correct.

Comment: How do you launch this modal?

Comment: I have a function on the click event of the edit button that sets the state isEditingAddress to true, which launches the modal.

Comment: I am thinking the modal needs to go outside of the loop, then the button click should pass the data to the parent component, which contains the modal and launch it at that point.

Comment: I cant figure out the problem,  you pass data.firstName to EditAddressModal, that data comes from savedAddresses.

Comment: yes that's right. I can see the firstName field being updated three times when the modal launches, so I think the modal needs to sit outside of the loop.